# C++ Classes dependent on each other causing a cyclic dependency error

Tags: c++, scope, redundancy, cyclic-dependency

My searches have lead me to believe that the problem I am experiencing is called cyclic redundancy. I don't understand any of the solutions that are posted. I am (fairly) new to C++, coming from a strong Java background.

Basically there are two classes that depend on each other. Class A contains a vector of class B objects, and class B contains methods that require class A objects as input.

Here's code that reproduces the problem.

According to codelite g++, the error is in school.h and is "person was not declared in this scope". It also says "template argument 1 is invalid" and "template argument number 2 is invalid". Then a couple of others, about non-class type "int" on all the vector functions that get invoked.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "person.h"
#include "school.h"

int main() {
    person p;   
    school s;
    std::cout << p.name << std::endl;
    s.personVect.push_back(p);
    std::cout << s.personVect.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.personVect.at(0).name << std::endl;
    p.test();
    return 0;
}
```

school.h

```
#ifndef SCHOOL_H
#define SCHOOL_H
#include <vector>
#include "person.h"

class school
{
public:
    school();
    ~school();

    std::vector<person> personVect;


};

#endif // SCHOOL_H
```

school.cpp

```
#include "school.h"    
school::school(){}    
school::~school(){}
```

person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "school.h"


class person {
public:

    std::string name;
    std::string phone;

    school doSomethingWithSchool();

    void test();

    person();
    ~person();

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

person.cpp

```
#include "person.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

person::person()
{
    name = "marcus";
    phone = "0400000000";
}

person::~person()
{
}

void person::test() {
    cout << this->name;
}
school person::doSomethingWithSchool() {
    school s; 
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is it "What should I do if I need this functionality?"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be resolved by designing you class relationships better.

A `Person` isn't composed of a `School`, so it doesn't need to have a School member.

A `School` has a collection of `Person` objects.

If you want a person to do something with a school, pass it as an argument. This way you can use *pointers* and *forward declarations* to solve the issue.

```
// Person.h
class School; // Forward declare school type.

// Person.cpp
Person::DoSomethingWithSchool(School* school);
```

Comment: You just reframed the question, you didn't answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the fact that school.h has an #include "person.h" statement, and person.h has an #include "school.h" statement.

## The solution

In the `school` class, instead of `vector<person>`, use `vector<person*>`. Instead of including person.h here, add the statement `class person;`. Assuming that your `school` class is eventually going to modify `person` objects somehow, put the `#include person.h` in your school.cpp file, after the statement `#include school.h`.

## The error explained

This is a step-by-step breakdown of what happens when compiling:

1. In main.cpp, you first include person.h. The preprocessor goes and finds person.h. Since you've never included it before, PERSON_H has not yet been defined and the ifndef PERSON_H is currently true. So we go to the next line in the file.
2. The **first** interesting thing that happens in this file is that PERSON_H gets defined (`#fdefine PERSON_H`). The next time you `#include` this file, the preprocessor is going to skip the whole file, right to the #endif.
3. The **second** interesting thing to happen is that school.h gets included. So the preprocessor finds school.h (we haven't yet processed the School class!), which until now has never been processed.
4. The first interesting thing in school.h (after the #define SCHOOL_H) is the **#include person.h**, so the preprocessor **returns** to person.h (we haven't yet processed the Person class either!). But this time, PERSON_H is already defined, so #ifndef PERSON_H is false, and the preprocessor skips to the #endif in that file (as I mentioned in (2)). So the Person class still hasn't been declared.
5. We return to school.h, having done nothing. At this point, we are just about to declare/define the school class. The person class has **never been declared** because our preprocessor jumped from person.h to school.h back to person.h back to school.h, only processing `#include` directives.
6. The compiler starts going through the `school` class definition. The next interesting thing is the line `std::vector<person> personVect;`. You have tried to instantiate a `vector<person>`. But `person` here is unknown (i.e. has not been declared in this scope) because of (5). This explains your two template argument errors: A `vector<person>` is actually implicitly a `vector <person, allocator<person> >`. The first template argument is `person` and the second is `allocator<person>`. Since `person` is unknown, both these arguments are invalid.

## The solution explained

The fact that school.h includes person.h, and person.h includes school.h, is what causes the cyclic dependency that you alluded to. To avoid this, we need an alternative way to declare that we are going to be using a particular class in a file. The common approach is to use a **forward declaration** - the statement `class person;` that I mentioned in the solution, before the definition of `school`. This is an ordinary declaration that lets the compiler know that `person` (as used in the `school` class) refers to a class.

However, in order to construct `vector<person>`, the compiler also needs to know how much space the class `person` occupies in memory (i.e. its size), which we aren't providing (and could never manually provide) with the declaration `class person;`. In fact, the compiler only knows the size of a class once the full definition in the header file has been processed. But if we try to do that, we're back to square one (cyclic dependency, and what not). What we do know is the size of a **pointer** to `person`, since that's machine specific (e.g. on a 32-bit machine, the size of a pointer to **anything** is 32 bits). Hence, we can instantiate a `vector<person*>` since this is always a vector of 32-bit objects regardless of what `person` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including person `#include "person.h"`
In header file ("school.h") just write `class person;` and use pointer to `person`
And in c++ module ("school.cpp") include "person.h" if you need.

This will also have some benefits in feature. (reduce compilation time)

Useful links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547275/Whyplusisplusitplusbuildingplussopluslong-3f
https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/328260

Comment: This will not work. As he is using instances and not pointers

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

person.h

```
        #ifndef PERSON_H
        #define PERSON_H
        #include <string>
        #include <vector>

        class school;
        class person {
        public:

            std::string name;
            std::string phone;

            school doSomethingWithSchool();

            void test();

            person();
            ~person();

        };

        #endif // PERSON_H
```

school.h

```
      #ifndef SCHOOL_H
      #define SCHOOL_H
      #include <vector>

      class person;
      class school
      {
      public:
          school();
          ~school();

          std::vector<person*> personVect;
      };

      #endif // SCHOOL_H
```

person.cpp

```
    #include "person.h"
    #include "school.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    person::person()
    {
        name = "marcus";
        phone = "0400000000";
    }

    person::~person()
    {
    }

    void person::test() {
        cout << this->name;
    }
    school person::doSomethingWithSchool() {
        school s; 
        return s;
    }
```

and in main.cpp

```
    int main()
    {
        person *p = new person;   
        school s;
        std::cout << p->name << std::endl;
        s.personVect.push_back(p);
        std::cout << s.personVect.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << s.personVect.at(0)->name << std::endl;
        p->test();
        delete p;
        return 0;
    }
```